# aerospike, golang -- get all bin names for all records

Tags: go, aerospike

Just wanted to check, if there is a way to get all bin names for every record ?

I know we can get the `binmap` using the following code. But I want to read all the keys and create a `map[string]interface{}` and then convert that map to byte array.

This is my code to get all the bins , add them to an array, convert array to byte array :

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
    as "github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

var client *as.Client


func main() {
    stmt := as.NewStatement("txn", "user")
    stmt.Addfilter(as.NewEqualFilter("p", "param"))
    rs, err := GetAerospikeClient().Query(nil, stmt)
    if err == nil {

        //Conv to byte array
        var ret []interface{}
        for res := range rs.Results() {
            if res.Err != nil {
                // handle error here
                // if you want to exit, cancel the recordset to release the resources
                fmt.Println("Err------", res.Err)

            } else {
                // process record here
                fmt.Printf("Success------%#v\n", res.Record.Bins)
                ret = append(ret, res.Record.Bins)
            }
        }

        b, _ := GetBytes(ret)
        fmt.Println("Len of byte array ", len(b))



    }

}

func GetAerospikeClient() *as.Client {
    var err error
    port, _ := strconv.Atoi("3000")
    maxconn, _ := strconv.Atoi("10")
    host := "172.28.128.3"
    timeout, _ := strconv.Atoi("50")
    idletimeout, _ := strconv.Atoi("3600")
    clientPolicy := as.NewClientPolicy()
    clientPolicy.ConnectionQueueSize = maxconn
    clientPolicy.LimitConnectionsToQueueSize = true
    clientPolicy.Timeout = time.Duration(timeout) * time.Millisecond
    clientPolicy.IdleTimeout = time.Duration(idletimeout) * time.Second
    client, err = as.NewClientWithPolicy(clientPolicy, host, port)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return client
}   

func GetBytes(key []interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    gob.Register(as.BinMap{})
    gob.Register([]interface{}{})
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)
    err := enc.Encode(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        return nil, err
    }
    return buf.Bytes(), nil
}
```

Thanks

Comment: added the full main function now....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the list of bins of a namespace, there is a much less expensive way. You do not need to do a query/scan which is very expensive. One catch is that you cannot get it per set. There is an info command `"bins/nsname"` (replace "nsname" with your desired namespace name) to get all the bins in that namespace.

If you do not care about a programmatic way of getting the binlist, you can get it using the `asinfo` tool provided with `aerospike-tools` package. You can issue the following command. The output is reasonably self explanatory. (Replace "127.0.0.1" with the proper IP address of the node)

> asinfo -v "bins/nsname" -h 127.0.0.1

If you want to get the list programmatically, You can use the `RequestInfo()` API as given in [this example](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/master/examples/info.go) and send the above command . You should write parser to extract the desirable fields.